# Column names are not loading correctly c# scripting in SSIS

Tags: c#, ssis

Im new to scripting in C# using SSIS so I'm not sure why this is happening. I'm using a script component to read some files. My column names that have _ "underscore" are not showing correctly
[image: Please look at this image to see what I mean]

The error code is this.
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'Output0Buffer' does not contain a definition for 'funded_amnt' and no accessible extension method 'funded_amnt' accepting a first argument of type 'Output0Buffer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Are you in fact supplying these columns to the script component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add columns to a Script task, I don't know the rules off the top of my head but, there is a translation that happens between Data Flow Column Name to the available name within a script task. Given that every column with an underscore in your data flow is reported to be in error, I'm guessing that is one of the valid characters in a column name that it doesn't allow in a Buffer's field name.

If I were to guess, underscores get eliminated as every column in a script has an _IsNull property added to it and perhaps multiple underscores would complicate logic somewhere.

Given a source query of

```
SELECT 1 AS col1, 2 AS col_underscore_2;
```

I get two columns in my data flow task named `col1` and `col_underscore_2`. Adding both to a script task

This is the resulting auto-generated definition of my input buffer (BufferWrapper.cs)

```
public class Input0Buffer: ScriptBuffer

{
    public Input0Buffer(PipelineBuffer Buffer, int[] BufferColumnIndexes, OutputNameMap OutputMap)
        : base(Buffer, BufferColumnIndexes, OutputMap)
    {
    }

    public Int32 col1
    {
        get
        {
            return Buffer.GetInt32(BufferColumnIndexes[0]);
        }
    }
    public bool col1_IsNull
    {
        get
        {
            return IsNull(0);
        }
    }

    public Int32 colunderscore2
    {
        get
        {
            return Buffer.GetInt32(BufferColumnIndexes[1]);
        }
    }
    public bool colunderscore2_IsNull
    {
        get
        {
            return IsNull(1);
        }
    }

    new public bool NextRow()
    {
        return base.NextRow();
    }

    new public bool EndOfRowset()
    {
        return base.EndOfRowset();
    }

}
```

Of note, it mangles `col_underscore_2` to an internal column name of `colunderscore2`. If you want to see the same for your, either double click on BufferWrapper.cs in Solution Explorer or put your cursor on `Input0Buffer` in the `public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)` and hit F12 (Go to Definition)

If you want to see the autogenerated columns,

I think a similar logic goes on with buffer names.

I assume you're attempting to auto generate the script task and you'll want to take that into consideration. Also, if the LendingClassRow could have a null, you'll need to have logic like

```
if(LendingClassRow.verification_status != null)
{
    Output0Buffer.verificationstatus = LendingClassRow.verification_status
}
// This entire block is not needed as it will be the default if no value is
// assigned but I call it out here in case future readers have a need to
// muck with it
else
{
    Output0Buffer.verificationstatus_IsNull = true;
}
```